# XCUITest: selecting a CollectionView cell from multiple cells identifier with multiple cell prototypes

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

i've been trying to tap() the correct Collection View cell, I can manage to tap() when there is only 1 cell prototypes, but I cant manage to select the correct cell based on the cell identifier when there are many cell prototypes with different identifiers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this to tap the second cell:

```
let secondCell = app.collectionViews.children(matching:.any).element(boundBy: 1)
if secondCell.exists {
     secondCell.tap()
}
```

or using a predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'test'")
let cell = app.collectionViews.cells.element(matching: predicate)
```

Comment: Your code works, thanks, but can we use cell identifier to determine which one to tap(), because if i change the position of the cell it wont be working anymore.

Comment: You can use a predicate to select cell having text for example but identifier is the same for all cells so you can't use it IMHO.